# Is there a way to list a single sku as multiple variations on eBay?

Tags: product, magento-1, products-management

Our client sells motor parts. So Product A may fit Car X, Car Y and Car Z. It's the same product sku. But they want to list each variation as a separate listing e.g. three listings:

1. Product A for Car X
2. Product A for Car Y
3. Product A for Car Z

eBay has a feature called Parts Compatibility Listing for these instances. http://www.ebay.com/autos/compatibility/FAQ/ListingFAQ.html

We have been considering using M2E Pro extension http://m2epro.com/ to manage listings on eBay and Amazon. It would be good to know if we can do it with this extension or similar.

We need to know if there is a better native solution than using an extension, or if using an extension, how best to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you from personal experience M2EPro you can accomplish this but the management can be a little bit of a headache if you have say more than 3-5 listing variations.

M2EPro does allow you to list the same product sku multiply times under different listings. So one way you could go about creating variations is create different listings that pull titles and/or any other variations that are needed to create the listings. This will require you to have add attributes for each listing variation.

So say that you want to list a particular sku in 3 variations which only differ in their titles and descriptions. You would need to add 3 ebay title attributes and 3 ebay description attributes to your product attribute set. Now when you create a listing template in M2EPro you create 3 different listings that point to the 3 different titles and description fields.

Sorry if this sounds confusing if you need more clarification let me know. This solution really only works if you have maybe 3-5 listing variations. If I'm right in thinking you situation may have cases that require a more variable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found this buried in M2E Pro docs http://docs.m2epro.com/display/M2EPro/2012/12/24/Major+Changes+in+M2E+Pro+v.+4.2.6#MajorChangesinM2EProv.4.2.6-eBayMotorsCompatibility - it seems to support eBay's Parts Compatibility Listing feature (http://www.ebay.com/autos/compatibility/FAQ/ListingFAQ.html)